# Are there alternatives to steam in thermal power stations?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, power, phase-transition, heat-engine

'A thermal power station is a power plant in which heat energy is converted to electric power. In most of the world the prime mover is steam driven. Water is heated, turns into steam and spins a steam turbine which drives an electrical generator.'

Why is H2O chosen? Shouldn't a liquid with a lower boiling point be used?

Also, why can't the following setups be used? Have they all been duly considered?

1) Expanding Liquid:
In this setup, a chosen liquid is heated, expanded, and used to push pistons, without getting boiled. As a liquid is hardly compressible, shouldn't the expansion generate a tremendous pressure? Furthermore, no latent heat is involved.

2) Expanding Empty Spiked Solid in a Liquid:
In this setup, a specially crafted empty solid is heated in a liquid to give rise to a large increase in volume. The liquid then pushes a piston.

3) Strong Balanced Bimetallic Strips:
In this setup, three sets of bimetallic strips/rods are used to push a piston when cooled (and bent when heated).

4) Expansion of Ice:
In this setup, freezing H2O in cold regions, natural or artificial, expands by about 9% and is used to push pistons.

Comment: You could use the setups, but think about the efficiency and the difficulties in building such equipment. It also needs to be reliable and produce a specific type of movement. For electric power stations (as an example) you have to have something that can drive the generator at a given constant RPM for months without a stop. There are other mediums that are used instead of steam in some nuclear power stations, as far as I can remember. Try looking up supercritical steam, it should be interesting for you.

Comment: See [Liquid Metal Cooled Reactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_metal_cooled_reactor)

Answer (score 3):

Expanding Liquid: the expansion per energy unit is tiny compared with the expansion at the phase transition from liquid to gas.

Expanding Solid:  even worse than expanding liquid

Bimetallic strips: very little energy transfer capability and long cool-down cycle.

Ice: see "expanding solid" above.

The next best choice after conversion of (any) liquid to gas is direct gaseous expansion as is done in internal combustion engines; the latter is far less efficient.

As to the choice of water: it's easily available, [relatively nontoxic](http://www.dhmo.org/truth/Dihydrogen-Monoxide.html) , and boils at a reasonable temperature: not terribly hot, but not so low that it boils at, say, room temperatures.

Comment: even if the expanding solid is empty inside and assumes a special structure?

Comment: even if we trap the expanding liquid in a container with a long, thin neck?

Comment: OTOH water is quite corrosive

Comment: @DirkBruere  yes, water's corrosivity is listed in my link :-) .

Answer (score 2):

Typically, modern gas powerplants use combined cycle and are projected to achieve over to [61 % thermal efficiency](http://www.gasturbineworld.com/ge-7ha.html), which is to my knowledge far highest of any contemporary technology. The first stage relies of thermal gas expansion similar to a jet engine, the second stage operating at lower temperature is the classical steam cycle. So the answer is *yes*.

Wikipedia also [lists alternative technologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combined_cycle) to the gas turbine in the first stage: *"Other historically successful combined cycles have used hot cycles with mercury vapor turbines, magnetohydrodynamic generators or molten carbonate fuel cells, with steam plants for the low temperature "bottoming" cycle."*

Answer (score 1):

A liquid with a lower boiling point would be better, however the boiling point still needs to be above ambient temperature, and there just aren't any liquids available with their boiling point at a better temperature and without other disadvantages.

Lower-temperature-boilingpoint liquids are used in thermal power generation when the high temperature is lower than in regular gas or coal fired plants, e.g. geothermal or solar plants. Here usually a hydrocarbon liquid is used, and this technology is known as the [organic rankine cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_Rankine_cycle). Hydrocarbons are nice because you can engineer them to have any boiling point you want, but they are not a good fit for regular power plants because they start to decompose at high temperatures.

There is also research into [supercritical CO$_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercritical_carbon_dioxide#Power_generation) powered turbines, however AFAIK that is not about thermal efficiency but about other advantages such as the smaller size or CO$_2$ capture. There is also research into [inert gas powered turbines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-cycle_gas_turbine), but there the main application is nuclear power plants.

Regarding your other setups, you seem to think that a lower expansion ratio is preferable. That's not the case, the higher the better. Boiling water has an expansion ration of about 1000, or 100000%, so try to beat that. Steam can also achieve any pressure you want, but the pressure limits are dictated by the construction materials, not the working medium.